# $L^{\prime}=\{x \# y \mid x y \in L, y x \notin L\}$ where $L$ is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Hey I'm trying to prove that the following Language is regular so far couldn't find a way, hope someone can help me $L^{\prime}=\{x \# y \mid x y \in L, y x \notin L\}$ where $L$ is regular.

Comment: We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-like task, so you might get some negative feedback about that.  We'd prefer conceptual questions that will be useful even to others who aren't looking at the same exact task you are.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: The same question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110084/l-x-y-xy-in-l-yx-notin-l-where-l-is-regular-prove-l-is).

Answer (score 3):

You can write this language as the intersection of two languages:
$$
\{ x \# y \mid  xy \in L \} \cap \{ y \# x \mid xy \notin L \}
$$
I assume you know how to handle the first one. As for the second one, construct an NFA that acts as follows:

- Start with a DFA for $L$.
- Guess which state the DFA will be on after reading $x$.
- Based on this guess, verify that after reading $xy$, the DFA reaches a rejecting state.
- Now read $x$ and verify your guess.

You take it from here.